# Difference between setModel( ) and getModel( ) in tabbed panes

Tags: blackberry, java-me

What is the actual difference between the terms `setModel()` and `getModel()` in tabbed panes (for blackberry).

BB docs notices these as being:

```
getModel()
   Returns the PaneManagerModel associated with this view.
```

Does this mean i get to access the methods and variables of code inside the pane associated with that model?

```
setModel()
   Lets you associate a PaneManagerModel with this view.
```

Does it only give access to set the usage of that pane for display in another pane?

Re edit:

I have used this piece of code to invoke method held inside another pane from first pane and now i want to refresh the display.But dont know how.Please guide.

```
    model.getController().getModel().getPane(1);

  //model.getPane(1).getPane().getScreen().getUiEngine().updateDisplay();

    model.getPane(1).getPane().getManager().invalidate();
```

What to use get or set?

Comment: I don't see how the description is ambiguous: `getModel()` returns the `PaneManagerModel` of the current view, `setModel()` associates a `PaneManagerModel` for the current view. Basically the view has a private attribute of type `PaneManagerModel` that you can get or set. Please refine your question unto what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

`getModel()` is a function that returns the `PaneManagerModel` field of the view.
`setModel()` allows you to set a `PaneManagerModel` field for your view.

This is a standard OO set/get situation. Here is a demonstration of it (so you get what it actually is, it doesn't necessarily work exactly like so)

```
public class View
{
  private PaneManagerModel model;
  public PaneManagerModel getModel()
  {
    return model;
  }
  public void setModel(PaneManagerModel me)
  {
    model = me;
  }
}
```

Edit: use set. Get only lets you get what is inside. If you want to put something new in, use set. If you want to trigger code that is only executed while you're setting but you want to keep the same `PaneManagerModel` use `setModel(getModel());` though it is ugly.

Comment: Thanks for responding.My lookout is to be able to update the display of the pane after re executing all the code(i.e Refresh the display) defined into it.What should I use now.

Comment: I tried this.  model.getController().setModel(getModel().getPane(1)); Its going horridly wrong man.

Comment: @learning_fly You are trying to set a `Pane` as a `PaneModelManager`. Of course it's going badly!!! do you have experience in development in java? or in BB?

Comment: I am naive in BB.A simple question i have is how to refresh display of second tab from first tab.Can u suggest any idea.

Comment: @learning_fly How would you refresh display of 2nd tab from 2nd tab? Please write the code in.

Comment: I am unaware of that either.:( All i know is to jump between the tab views.Havent been able to figure rerunning of implementations.Would be nice if u could pls guide.

Comment: I have tried out updating display this way too.But no aid. model.getPane(1).getPane().getScreen().getUiEngine().updateDisplay();

Comment: @learning_fly 1st find out how to refresh one tab from itself. Then start trying to do this from other tabs. Google some about it.

Comment: Yeah you are right.But feels like theres no way outta this.Tried all possibilities.

Comment: @learning_fly the way out is looking at how it's done. simply poking around an API never really helps

Comment: Refreshing of the same pane would never be needed though.Coz when the pane starts it loads with all the data.Only when there are statements manipulating a pane from external pane would there be a need.Hence reload of same tabs is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong and wrong

getModel gets you the underlying PanelManagerModel. The Model handles data, and is totally separate from methods / code in the pane

setModel lets you set the underlying datamodel of your panel, but has nothing to do with display, except for setting the elements to be displayed.

This is strictly about the data items in your tabbed pane

Comment: "Data items in tabbed pane" mean exactly what.Is it the UI components going into defining the pane view?My lookout is to be able to update the display of the pane after re executing all the code(i.e Refresh the display) defined into it.What should I use now.

Answer (score 1):

It's all related to the concepts of "setter" and "getter".

A "Setter", which in this case is setModel(), lets you set a new Model on the View. On the other hand a "Getter" allows you to obtain a certain property of a certain object. In this case the getter gives you access to the currently set Model of the View.

Comment: pretty much what I said, no? :P

Comment: Well, there is theorically one answer to this question... and I didn't see your answer or comment until I posted mine :P

Comment: @Gamb Thanks for responding.My lookout is to be able to update the display of the pane after re executing all the code(i.e Refresh the display) defined into it.I am confused as to how i can do it.Any idea.